# How to change text of a cell at runtime in XtraReport?

Tags: text, devexpress, runtime, xtrareport

How to change text of a cell at runtime in XtraReport?
I am using "DevExpress v2011 vol 1".
I have a few cells and I can change their text one by one using PreviewClick event as below.

```
private void _cell_PreviewClick(object sender, PreviewMouseEventArgs e)
{
    e.Brick.Text = "aaabbbccc"; e.PreviewControl.Refresh();
}
```

But, in that event I need to change text of other cells simultaneously. I tried below and got no luck

```
private void _cell_PreviewClick(object sender, PreviewMouseEventArgs e)
{
    e.Brick.Text = "aaabbbcc";
    otherCell1.Text = "rrrttcwwww"
    e.PreviewControl.Refresh();
}
```

Best Regards,
Orgil.D

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the DataSourceRowChanged event of the XtraReport Class

```
private void rpt_DataSourceRowChanged(object sender, DataSourceRowEventArgs e)
{
            MyClass xx = bidingSource[e.CurrentRow] as MyClass ;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xx.WorkDescription))
            {
                xrTableCell25.Visible = false;
                xrTableRow3.Visible = false;
                xrTableCell25.Text = "456";
            }
            else
            {
                xrTableCell25.Visible = true;
                xrTableRow3.Visible = true;
                xrTableCell25.Text = "123";
            }
```

}